# Solving for the probability of an disjoint event

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let $S$ be the sample space for an experiment $D$. If A, B are disjoint events from $S$ with $P_r(A) = 0.3$ and $P_r(A\cup B) = 0.7$ what is  $P_r(B)$?

and have made it to;

$Pr(A\cup B) = Pr(A) + pr(B) - P(A \cap B) \\ 
0.7 = .3 +P_r(B) - P_r(A \cap B) \\
0.4 = p_r(B) - P_r(A \cap B)$

coincidently $P_r(B)$ is equal to $0.4$

My question is how do I go about solving for $P_r(B)$ algebraically with what I currently have?

Comment: If the events are disjoint then $\Pr(A \cap B)=0$

Comment: @Henry Thank you for clarifying that for me. It's been a pretty long day, tackling an array of topics. But I see how that make sense, given that they are disjoint meaning that the intersection of the two sets would be an empty set. Please feel free to post that as an answer an I will accept, it might help someone else having a tough time with discrete mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in comments:

If the events are disjoint then $\Pr(A \cap B)=0$.